# What should a Jew do if he got a non-Jew pregnant?

Tags: gentiles, sexuality, children-parenting, pregnancy-birth, men-male

This is NOT a situation that I or anyone I know is facing. It is hypothetical.

Imagine that a Jewish man impregnates a gentile woman. The woman refuses to convert. Which (if any) of the following courses of action is considered optimal?

1. Encourage the woman to have an abortion
2. Do not encourage the woman to have an abortion, but avoid further involvement with her and the child to the extent permitted by secular law / considerations of chillul hashem
3. Take on paternal responsibilities without further sexual or romantic involvement with the mother
4. Some other option

Obviously one ideally simply avoids this situation… but if it's occurred, what ought one to do?

Comment: FYI I've heard that Orthodox Batei Din don't convert pregnant women by policy, so her lack of desire to convert is moot.

Comment: @robev missing the point; if she was sincere about converting, they'd happily convert her and the baby a few months after the birth.

Comment: What's the difference between 2 and 3? If she sues for child support in courts, it's going to cause a massive Chilul Hashem. (Rabbi Moshe Feinstein employed that logic in a different case.) Being a good Jew means not continuing with her romantically; being a good human being means providing whatever support is needed. Find the best intersection between those two.

Comment: @Shalom One could conceivably provide child support on a private basis without the involvement of the courts or the public's eye. The question is the degree of personal involvement beyond that necessitated by prevailing secular laws & considerations of chillul hashem.